# Can you specify filenames using wildcards or regexes in the subversion mv command?

Tags: svn

I want to do this so that I can say something like, `svn mv *.php php-folder/`, but it does not seem to be working.  Is it even possible?  No mention of it is made on the relevant page in the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re18.html).

Example output of `svn mv *.php php-folder/` :
`svn: Client error in parsing arguments`

Being able to move a whole file system would be a plus, so if any answers given could try to include that ability, that'd be cool.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure about svn itself, but either your shell should be able to expand that wildcard and svn can take multiple source arguments, or you can use something like

```
for file in *.php; do svn mv $file php-folder/; done
```

in a bash shell, for example.

Answer (score 14):

svn move only moves one file at a time.  Your best bet is a shell loop.  In Bash, try

```
for f in *.php ; do svn mv $f php-folder/; done
```

On Windows, that's

```
for %f in (*.php) do svn mv %f php-folder/
```

**Edit:** Starting with Subversion 1.5, `svn mv` accepts multiple source files, so your original command would work.  The shell loop is only needed for svn 1.4.x and earlier.  (Of course, the shell loop will still work with 1.5; it just isn't necessary.)

Comment: Can this be easily expanded for the traversing of a whole file hierarchy?  Is this something that git does easily?

Answer (score 1):

`find . -name "*.php" -exec svn mv {} php-folder \;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the correct checked out directory, I don't see why it wouldn't work?  Your shell should expand the *.php to a list of php files, and svn move accepts multiple sources as arguments.

Comment: Where do you see svn move accepting more than one source argument ?

Comment: From 'svn help move':

move (mv, rename, ren): Move and/or rename something in working copy or repository.
usage: move SRC... DST

When moving multiple sources, they will be added as children of DST,
which must be a directory.

Comment: That's new in Subversion 1.5, which many people haven't upgraded to yet.  Obviously, stopsineman is one of them, or he wouldn't have gotten the error in the first place.