# What is your preferred method for moving directory structures around in Subversion?

Tags: svn

I have recently run into an issue where I wanted to add a folder to the directory structure of my project that would become the new 'root' directory for the previously housed files.  I've been getting help in a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87458/can-you-specify-filenames-using-wildcards-or-regexes-in-the-subversion-mv-comma) but I wanted to put out a more open ended question to see what a best practice might be.

Essentially, my situation was that I was working on development and realized that I wanted to have a resources directory that would not be part of the main development thrust but would still be versioned (to hold mockups and such).  So I wanted to add a resources directory and an implementation directory, the implementation directory being the new root directory.  How would you go about moving all of the previous directory structure into the implementation directory?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it pretty easily if you use some GUI for SVN. Personally I love [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) for when I'm working in Windows. You just open up the "Repository Browser", right-click on some folder, and choose "Move...". Or, you have the option of doing it straight from within Windows Explorer, drag the files/folders you want to move with the RIGHT mouse button, when you drop them in their new location you'll get a menu, one of the options is "Move in SVN".

Comment: Does this have any effect on being able to get older revisions of these files? As I understand it, a move is actually a "delete" of the files in the original location, and an "add" of the files in the new location.

Comment: nope, it actually does preserve the history. A move is actually implemented as a "copy" and then a "delete". And since branch and tag are actually implemented as "copy" as well, they all preserve history in the same way.

Comment: depending on how you do it, don't forget to switch your working copy afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Moves in subversion are done by removing the old files and adding the new ones, so there's nothing special to do. The series of 'svn mv' commands in a loop recommended in the other question should probably work just fine.

Comment: To be more precise: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html says a svn move is equivalent to a svn copy then svn delete. And since svn copies are cheap copies, svn moves are also cheap.