# Subversion: How to svn rm using wildcards?

Tags: svn

I'm trying to remove all of the "dot underscore" files in a direcoty. This is what I am trying to do:

```
svn rm dir1/dir2/._*
```

But this does not work. How can I accomplish this? By the way, I'm doing this on Ubuntu.

**Update**: This will probably work if you haven't deleted the files already:

```
cd dir1/dir2
for file in ._*; do svn rm $file; done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you specify filenames using wildcards or regexes in the subversion mv command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87458/can-you-specify-filenames-using-wildcards-or-regexes-in-the-subversion-mv-command). They're the same question, even though one refers to `mv` and this one to `rm`

Comment: @KenWhite: It looks like a duplicate, but it's not. Also, I have already tried all the commands suggested in that post and none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the shell expansion didn't work. Are there any files matching `._*` in `dir1/dir2/`? You can use `echo dir1/dir2/._*` to make sure.

Comment: Good point. The files don't actually exist anymore because they were  already deleted manually. Since they have already been deleted, I can't select them in this way.

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I have problems passing patterns to a command is to list the patterns into a file and then edit the file to turn it into a script with one command for target file. That either works or gives me detailed information about what I'm doing wrong.

You could try enclosing the pattern in double quotes first.